# I use ubuntu to build my android project，but I can not use VerticalGridView，I need help！

Tags: aar, android.mk

VerticalGridView rely on recyclerview,but when I import support package in Android.mk,the aar package conflict.what can I do to use VerticalGridView？

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView

Answer (score 1):

I add something to Android.mk,and the problem solved

```
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
```

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/appcompat/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v17/leanback/res

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v17.leanback